# What is node_modules directory in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What is the usage of node_modules directory in ember?

I could see this directory created accross my ember application. When does it get created and what is the significance?

What harm if i delete this directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a directory for `npm`/`yarn`. It's created by running `npm install` or yarn. Theese commands install all dependecies specified in the `package.json` file into the `node_modules` directory. You need them to run any ember commands. If you delete the folder you can recreate it with `npm install`/`yarn`. It's not checked into source control.

Comment: Got it!!  Thanks!! :)

Comment: One more thing - it's a normal directory for almost any JavaScript project. It's not unique to Ember.